# How do I setup ethernet-only SSH?

Tags: networking, nautilus, ssh, ethernet

On my pair of Ubuntu systems, a 3 MB file transfer via **Nautilus 2.32** over SSH takes about 15 seconds between two computers with identical wireless cards 2 meters apart.

Larger files take significantly longer, so the 15 seconds is not dominated by handshaking.  This data rate seems unsatisfactory and obviously it would get worse if I were concurrently using the wireless cards for internet access.

I have a 20 meter (About 65 feet) Ethernet cable, coiled down to 2 meters, between the two computers but that physical medium is probably not being used for SSH because when I disable wireless, each Nautilus cannot see the other machine.

How do I setup SSH for the Ethernet cable exclusively?

Comment: Sounds like a)the default route isn't getting updated, b)you need to use the ethernet IP address since it's thinking the wireless one is unreachable, or c)you need policy routing to match on the port number.

Comment: Is the cable plugged directly from one computer to another? you may need a switch between the computers, or a "crossover adapter"

Comment: Close-voters: This has [an answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/249116/22949) now, so there's no longer a reason to close it as abandoned/TL.

Answer (score 5):

#### Create your own small network

Make up a nice small subnet in the private IP space, e.g. `10.1.2.0`/`24`. This is for 254 hosts, and overkill, but it's easy in calculation and entering details.

I'm assuming you have either a switch connected between the two or using a network cable that is suitable for your two PCs to be connected to each other directly. Most modern network cards feature [Auto MDI/MDIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_Dependent_Interface), so no need for a crossover cable.

Below is a list of steps to have PC1: `10.1.2.1` and PC2: `10.1.2.2`.

#### On PC1

1. Go to *Edit connections*.

   [image]
2. Add a new connection.

   [image]
3. Fill in a name, e.g. *Cross-cable connection*
4. Select the right interface from the "Device MAC address field":

   [image]
5. Then on the *IPv4 Settings* tab, add the following details and take the steps as shown in the image.

   - Method: *Manual*
   - Address: `10.1.2.1`
   - Netmask: `24`
   - Gateway: `0.0.0.0` (this means 'none' in IPv4)

   [image]
6. Establish the connection using the network menu:

   [image]

#### On PC2

Follow the same steps, on one exception: enter `10.1.2.2` as IP address.

Now, you should be able to 'ping' PC1 from PC2:

```
ping -c3 10.1.2.1
PING 10.1.2.1 (10.1.2.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.1.2.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.661 ms
```

And establish a connection with Nautlius using the IP addresses we just assigned.